# SQL statement with like and parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I have a search window, person enters what they are looking for and click on next.

In my sql statement I would like my parameter to search into my tables BILNAME and CUSTOMER.

I added Like because I want my client to enter only 2 letters and it looks everywhere in the words.

Here is what I have, now, my loop goes directly to the error message when I debug I see that my table count is 0.

My guess is that the problem comes from the SQL statement.

```
private void btn_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionstring = "...";
    string sql = ("SELECT * FROM C3 WHERE BILNAME  LIKE @search OR CUSTOMER LIKE @search");

    mycommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + clsDataSource.search + "%");

    myadapt = new SqlDataAdapter(mycommand);

    myset = new DataSet();
    myadapt.Fill(myset, "C3");
    mytable = myset.Tables["C3"];

    if (mytable.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DisplayWindow displaywindow = new DisplayWindow();
        displaywindow.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
    else if (mytable.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
        GUI.Multipleresult multipleresultDisplay = new GUI.Multipleresult();
        multipleresultDisplay.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing found, please try again", "No result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        SearchWindow searchWindowDisplay = new SearchWindow();    
        searchWindowDisplay.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
   }}
```

Comment: You need to surround it with single quotes e.g. LIKE '%searchvalue%'

Comment: @Kevin - No, you don't. You do that then the search will filter on the actual character `'` at the beginning and end.

Comment: @Igor only if the single quotes are inside the % would the LIKE filter on them and then they would have to be doubled up

Comment: @Kevin - That is incorrect. When using parameters you do not add additional single quote. The parameter should provide the direct string value. Having a parameter value of `'%searchvalue%'` will limit the search to table values that start and end with the `'` character (*as well as the middle part %searchValue% which I do not think is being disputed*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) keyword

```
SELECT * FROM C3 WHERE BILNAME LIKE @search OR CUSTOMER LIKE @search
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot it! Thank you!

Comment: When I use that SQL statement, my if statement doesn't work, if I have one result it goes directly to my second loop which it should not

Comment: @Cbz What do you mean by *"my if statement doesn't work"*? There are no loops in the code you showed.

Comment: My if statement doesn't work. It doesn't count properly.

Comment: Does your SQL statement work in Management studio? Do you get any results there?